# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException -> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BOOT-INF

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a maven project in intellij. I used JPA in my application and i connect remote machine in my application. Then run my application intellij. It's work fine. After I i build runnable jar.
Now this jar is transfer my remote machine and deploy and run but i got this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BOOT-INF/classes/com/avanir/mdm/app/model/hcp/MdmId (wrong name: com/avanir/mdm/app/model/hcp/MdmId)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:757)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:406)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.NativeScanner.getClassesInJar(NativeScanner.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addMetadataFromScan(Ejb3Configuration.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:361)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at com.avanir.mdm.app.impl.hcp.HcpSingleton.getEntityManager(HcpSingleton.java:52)
    at com.avanir.mdm.app.impl.hcp.HcpSingleton.getNextMdmId(HcpSingleton.java:25)
    at com.avanir.mdm.app.impl.hcp.HcpImpl.loadHcpDataIntoCassandra(HcpImpl.java:248)
    at com.avanir.mdm.app.impl.hcp.HcpImpl.CreateHcpMasterData(HcpImpl.java:30)
    at com.avanir.mdm.client.snowflake.SnowflakeConClient.main(SnowflakeConClient.java:23)
    ... 8 more
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.avanir.mdm</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>MDM-APP-SERVER</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.snowflake</groupId>
            <artifactId>snowflake-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--  Jersy json jar file -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependency for JSONObject-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <!-- JSON object dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/it.dontesta.labs.liferay.salesforce.client.soap/salesforce-client-soap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>it.dontesta.labs.liferay.salesforce.client.soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>salesforce-client-soap</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.force.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>force-wsc</artifactId>
            <version>48.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/ST4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>ST4</artifactId>
            <version>4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mozilla/rhino -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mozilla</groupId>
            <artifactId>rhino</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-util</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.avanir.mdm.client.snowflake.SnowflakeConClient</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

persistence.xml :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="sql-connection">

        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.avanir.mdm.app.model.hcp.MdmId</class>
        <properties>
            <!--property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"   value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" /-->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/> <!--change root user-->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="Avanir"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://52.25.14.247:3306/mdm"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

class file :-

```
package com.avanir.mdm.app.model.hcp;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "mdm_id")
public class MdmId {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "last_updated_mdm_id")
    String updatedMdmId;

    public String getUpdatedMdmId() {
        return updatedMdmId;
    }

    public void setUpdatedMdmId(String updatedMdmId) {
        this.updatedMdmId = updatedMdmId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return updatedMdmId;
    }
}
```